# Hugo warnings for R blogdown with hugo (academic theme): Do I need to do anything?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I've started getting warnings everytime I do a build in blogdown

In RStudio, I run the code:

```
blogdown::serve_site()
```

The site is rendered fine, but I get the following warnings.

```
Building sites â€¦ WARN 2020/02/19 17:13:53 Page.Hugo is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use the global hugo function.
WARN 2020/02/19 17:13:53 Page.RSSLink is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use the Output Format's link, e.g. something like: 
    {{ with .OutputFormats.Get "RSS" }}{{ .RelPermalink }}{{ end }}
WARN 2020/02/19 17:13:53 .File.TranslationBaseName on zero object. Wrap it in if or with: {{ with .File }}{{ .TranslationBaseName }}{{ end }}
WARN 2020/02/19 17:13:53 Page.Dir is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use .File.Dir
WARN 2020/02/19 17:13:53 Page.UniqueID is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use .File.UniqueID
WARN 2020/02/19 17:13:54 Page.URL is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use .Permalink or .RelPermalink. If what you want is the front matter URL value, use .Params.url
```

I'm just wondering, do I need to do anything, or will these issues be addressed by:

1. blogdown package in R? or
2. hugo academic them? or
3. both? or
4. someone/thing else???

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the warning messages is to inform you that your site is using functions or referencing variables that are or will be deprecated and removed from future releases of Hugo. If they are not changed before they are removed from Hugo, your website might not build.

Now, to answer your question: Unless you have manually edited your layout files or made changes to the Academic theme, these warnings will (should) be addressed by the developers of Academic. What you need to do, is make sure to update the theme [when new releases are available](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/updates/).